# Error in Windows Docker git: cd: .git: Not a directory

Tags: windows, git, docker, git-submodules

I have a Windows 10 host with a `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019` Docker image,

git was installed via

```
RUN powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned `
  iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://get.scoop.sh'); `
  scoop install python git
```

My git repo has submodules. When I checkout the repo locally and try to build it via

```
docker run --rm -it -v %cd%:C:\Temp -w C:\Temp buildtools2019 cmd.exe /C build.bat
```

I get the following error when git tries to update submodules (I use CMake as a build system):

```
-- Submodule update
/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 365: cd: .git: Not a directory
Unable to determine absolute path of git directory
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:47 (message):
  git submodule update --init failed with 1, please checkout submodules
```

But when I just start the container, make `git clone` inside the container and then execute my batch script, git has no problems. What is the difference between the cloned repo and the mapped one?

**Edit:** Mapped folder list:

```
PS C:\TEMP> dir


    Directory: C:\TEMP


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        1/27/2022   6:59 AM                .git
d-----        1/26/2022   6:01 PM                src
-a----        1/26/2022   6:01 PM             88 .gitmodules
-a----        1/26/2022   6:01 PM            162 build.bat
```

This is the routine where the issue occurs:

```bash
# Make sure we are in a valid repository of a vintage we understand,
# if we require to be in a git repository.
git_dir_init () {
        GIT_DIR=$(git rev-parse --git-dir) || exit
        if [ -z "$SUBDIRECTORY_OK" ]
        then
                test -z "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)" || {
                        exit=$?
                        gettextln "You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree." >&2
                        exit $exit
                }
        fi
        test -n "$GIT_DIR" && GIT_DIR=$(cd "$GIT_DIR" && pwd) || {
                gettextln "Unable to determine absolute path of git directory" >&2
                exit 1
        }
        : "${GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY="$(git rev-parse --git-path objects)"}"
}
```

I can change into any directory while I'm still in the shell, but from inside of this script, I can change only into the folders outside of the mounting point i.e. `c:\TEMP`.

Comment: Clearly the default setup *doesn't* clone the repository. (It probably just brings over the files from the working tree. Or, if you're using GitHub or similar, it might download a zip archive instead of cloning the repository. Either way you don't have a repository so you can't get the submodules into place that way. You might want to fuss with the cmake file: I don't use it myself but I understand it has ways to do this sort of thing "out of the box".)

Comment: @torek perhaps, I was not clear enough. If I invoke `git submodule update --init` manually in both powershell or cmd environment, I get the same error. The problematic case is, when my current source tree is mapped into Docker container. From inside of the `git-sh-setup` script I can change to any folder outside of the "mounting" point but inside `C:\TEMP` it cannot change into any folder.

Comment: The "not a directory" error suggests that either `.git` is a file (which is normal for submodules: it's a file containing the relative pathname to the superproject's `.gitmodules` holding the submodule) or nonexistent. If your build process doesn't start by cloning locally *in* the container, it *should do so* because in-container paths may not match out-of-container paths.

Comment: I have added the mounting point tree as also the routine in the `git-sh-setup` script where the problem occurs. If I set `GIT_DIR` to `src` it will throw the same error that `src is not a directory`. With Docker 3.x the same setup was working. There is just something wrong or different in the way mounting point tree is handled in the git scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I opened a [ticket](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3654) on git-for-windows project page. The problem could be narrowed down to msys2 but the dubugging is stilll not finished.

For now, there is a workaround: use git 2.11.0.

```
ADD https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.11.0.windows.1/Git-2.11.0-64-bit.exe git.exe
RUN c:\git.exe /SP- /VERYSILENT /NORESTART /NOCANCEL /CLOSEAPPLICATIONS /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS -Wait -NoNewWindow; `
        Remove-Item -Force git.exe
```